# Get the title of each page and display it in header in Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have designed a page with Iframe where it is connected to multiple pages via Iframe. I have to display the heading of the each page in the top to which it gets navigates. Say I'm having a topnav with headings and when I click each nav buttons it display different page down in Iframe. I have to add title for each page in topnav.

```
<HTML>  
<title></title> 
<head> </head>
<body> <div id="wrapper" class="animate">   
<nav class="navbar header-top fixed-top navbar-expand-lg">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="file:///C:/Users/ajay.venkatesh/Desktop/sample.html">    
    <img src="C:\Users\ajay.venkatesh\Desktop\West_End.png">
</a>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
    <ul class="navbar-nav animate side-nav"></ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav ml-md-auto d-md-flex"> 
    <div class="dropdown">   <button class="dropbtn" style="color:black">
     <a href="C:\Users\ajay.venkatesh\Downloads\BeFunky-collage.png" target="iframe_a">
         Home<span class="caret"></span></a></button>
 </div>
 <div class="dropdown">   <button class="dropbtn" style="color:black"> 
     Dispatch Tools<span class="caret"></span></button>   <div class="dropdown-content" id="formLogin">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="container-fluid">
   <form>
    <ul class="opt"> <li><a href=   "file:///C:/Users/ajay.venkatesh/Desktop/With_orders.html" 
     target="iframe_a">Interactive Texting</a></li> <li><a href=  
     "file:///C:/Users/ajay.venkatesh/Desktop/Owner_OperatorA.html   "
     target="iframe_a">Owner Operator</a></li> <li><a href=  
     "http://as400.mandh.us/cgi-bin/DRVADMINC.pgm"  target="iframe_a">With
    Containers</a></li>
   </ul>
  </form>
</div>
</div>   </div> </div>

<div class="dropdown">   <button class="dropbtn" style="color:black">
Order Entry<span class="caret"></span></button>  
<div class="dropdown-content" id="formLogin">
<div class="row">
<div class="container-fluid">
<form> <ul class="opt"> <li><a href="http://as400.mandh.us/cgi-bin/LT001C.pgm?m=" 
target="iframe_a">LTL Entry</a></li> <li><a
href="http://as400.mandh.us/cgi-bin/LT001C.pgm?m=T"
target="iframe_a">LTL Test Entry</a></li> <li><a
href="http://as400.mandh.us/cgi-bin/DS001C.pgm?m=T" 
target="iframe_a">Dispatch Test Entry</a></li>  <li><a
href="file:///C:/Users/ajay.venkatesh/Desktop/css_trick.html" 
target="iframe_a">Common Entries</a></li>

                 </ul>
               </form>
             </div>
           </div>   </div> </div>

     <div class="dropdown">   <button class="dropbtn" style="color:black">
     Trucking<span class="caret"></span></button>   <div class="dropdown-content" id="formLogin">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="container-fluid">
                   <form>
                 <ul class="opt"> <li><a href=   "C:\Users\ajay.venkatesh\Desktop\Trucking_Customers.html"   
 target="iframe_a">Customers</a></li>
                </ul>
               </form>
             </div>
           </div>   </div> </div>

     <div class="dropdown">   <button class="dropbtn" style="color:black">
     Others<span class="caret"></span></button>   <div class="dropdown-content" id="formLogin">
           <div class="row">
             <div class="container-fluid">
               <form>
                 <ul class="opt "> <li><a href="   http://as400.mandh.us/cgi-bin/DRVCNTC.PGM??m=T&account=OO&driver=xxx" 
 target="iframe_a">Test Mobile App</a></li>
                 </ul>
               </form>
             </div>
           </div>   </div> </div>
       <div class="dropdown">   <button class="dropbtn" style="color:black"><a href=  
 "file:///C:/Users/ajay.venkatesh/Desktop/wexi2308_err.html#myPage" 
 target="iframe_a">
     About us<span class="caret"></span></a></button>

 </div>

 <li class="nav-item editLink">    &nbsp; <img border="0"
 onclick="history.back()"  alt="W3Schools" 
 src="C:\Users\ajay.venkatesh\Desktop\previous.png"  width="45"
 height="45"></a>
         </li>


         <li class="nav-item editLink">
         &nbsp; <img border="0" onclick="history.forward()" alt="W3Schools" src="C:\Users\ajay.venkatesh\Desktop\next.png"
 width="45" height="45"></a>
           </li>

         </ul>
       </div>
       &nbsp;
            <div class="dropdown">
     <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i5zqnxol/n179/fn7/fs20/tct/pct/ftb/th2"
           frameborder="0" width="128" height="30" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>

 </div>
     </nav>

 <table border=0 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0 id="hold_my_iframe">
 <iframe src="C:\Users\ajay.venkatesh\Downloads\BeFunky-collage.png" 
 width=100% height=85% name="iframe_a" marginwidth=0  marginheight=0
 frameborder=0></iframe> </table>

   </div> </body> </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what's the question?

Comment: Please properly format your code (remove all >). Also change all hardcoded paths to relative paths. You have to do that anyway or it won't work anywhere but on your PC. The `title` tag should also be in your `head` tag

Comment: I have updated @SuperDJ

Comment: My question is I want to display all the pages of Iframe titles @DarrenSweeney